# how to open child page popup in main page?

Tags: asp.net, iframe, popup

page structure-
Page1 = aspx page with iframe(Page2)
page2= aspx page contain user control
usercontrol UC = have a link

`Problem-` if I click any link of US there is a popup message but the problem is that popus comes inside the I-frame.**I want that popup on my main page (page 1)**

Comment: can you post the html of your UserControl and what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the link point to `window.top.location = your url;`